# TypeScript - Type Inference with keyof keyword

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have an abstract class

```
export abstract class ABaseModel {
  public static isKeyOf<T>(propName: (keyof T)): string {
    return propName;
  }
}
```

And another class that extends it

```
export class Model extends ABaseModel {

  public id: number;
  public uid: string;
  public createdByUid: string;
}
```

To check if a string is a valid property of that class, I have to wirte

```
Model.isKeyOf<Model>('id');
```

But I want to write

```
Model.isKeyOf('id');
```

Isn't it possible with Type Inference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
abstract class ABaseModel {
    public static isKeyOf<T>(this: { new(): T }, propName: (keyof T)): string {
        return propName;
    }
}

Model.isKeyOf("id"); // ok
Model.isKeyOf("name"); // error: Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"id" | "uid" | "createdByUid"'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20ABaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20isKeyOf%3CT%3E(this%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D%2C%20propName%3A%20(keyof%20T))%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20propName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Model%20extends%20ABaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20uid%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20createdByUid%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AModel.isKeyOf(%22id%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0AModel.isKeyOf(%22name%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22name%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'%22id%22%20%7C%20%22uid%22%20%7C%20%22createdByUid%22'))

Comment: Getting error: The 'this' context of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => Model'.

Comment: What's the signature of your `Model` class? It should be the same, for example if it's `class Model { constructor(a: string, b: number) { ... } }` then you should use: `(this: { new(a: string, b: number): T }`

Comment: The constructor is 
`constructor(props: any[]) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }`

So it works with

`public static isKeyOf<T>(this: { new ({ }): T }, propName: (keyof T)): string {
        return propName;
    }`

Great, thanks a lot!